# Desgining an solving exitable circuit by Matlab ode45

Tags: matlab, ode

I'm working on non-linear circuit of Excitable Dynamical system. Simply we can solve its nonlinear equation by Matlab "Ode45" using inital condition. But I need to stimulate it by directly input (external stimulus; not initial condition). How can I define square pulse as a current source (with preferred time onset) in the first equation (DV)?

```
clear;close all;clc 
gfi = 0.2308;      gso = 0.769;        Efi = 17.333;    Eso = 0;  TAu=3; 

Km = 0.842;         v12m = 5.85;       Kn = 4.4;      v12n = 9.667;  
C =0.01;  a=6;

DV  =  @(v,no,ni)   (-1/C)*((gfi*(v-Efi))/(1+exp((v12m-v)/Km))+gso*(no*ni)*(v-Eso)); 
Dno =  @(v,no,TAu) (1/TAu)*((1/(1+exp((v12n-v)/Kn)))-no); 
Dni =  @(v,ni,TAu) (1/a*TAu)*((1/(2+exp((v12n-v)/-Kn)))-ni); 

EDS= @(v,no,ni,TAu)[DV(v,no,ni);Dno(v,no,TAu);Dni(v,ni,TAu)]; 

[T,Y] = ode45(@(t, x) EDS(x(1), x(2) ,x(3),TAu),[0 25], [11,0.1,0.90]);
```